# How to plot multiple values in CSV file in one plot?

Tags: python, csv

first of all please do not judge my English i am not native.

i have a large CSV  file,  i have a round 84000 column and and 5 row as follow :

```
filename    max     probability  size_start size_end
   file1     33     0.001         30          10
   file2     4      0.001         30          10
   file3     50     0.001         40          10
   file4     0      0.001         50          10
```

i would like to plot `probability`  against the `max`  for each pair of `size_start and start end`  , i have 10 different pair of start and end.
i think i have to do a for loop or while loop to loop over the start and the end and plot the corresponded  values for the probability and max but i do not know how to loop over csv file . please enlighten me if you have any idea about the answer.

Comment: What should the plot look like? a scatter plot, e.g. `probability` on the x axis and `max` on the y axis? or perhaps a bar plot or something else?

Comment: line plot or scatter plot are working for me

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you need one plot for each start/end combination? Do you really have 84k _columns_ or _rows_?

Comment: 84k columns, means 84k file ...yes for each combination for example i have (10,30) start and end i want to plot the corresponded  values of  probability on x axis  and max on the y axis, and on the same plot for (20,30)  start and end i want to plot the corresponded  values of  probability on x axis  and max on the y axis .. and on for all the 10 pairs.. i hope it is clear

Answer (score 0):

You could use Panda's [`DataFrame.plot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) method, after subdividing your data into groups:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
for (size_start, size_end), group in df.groupby(['size_start', 'size_end']):
    ax = group.plot(x='probability', y='max', kind='scatter')
    ax.get_figure().savefig(f'plot_{size_start}_{size_end}.png')
```

This will create a separate image for each size_start/size_end combination. There are many options to customize the design and layout of the plot, have a look at the documentation.

If you want to combine the plots all into the same diagram, you can simply call the `plot()` function multiple times:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
for (size_start, size_end), group in df.groupby(['size_start', 'size_end']):
    plt.plot('probability', 'max', data=group, label=f'{size_start} / {size_end}')

plt.xlabel('probability')
plt.ylabel('max')
plt.legend()
plt.show() # or plt.savefig('figure.png')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, it worked but each pair of start_size and end_size is plotted in seperet plot, is there a way to plot them all together in the same plot like in this plot        https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oCrX.png